# How can I change taxonomy term id to name in Drupal 7

Tags: view, drupal-7, alias, custom-taxonomy

Using the View Option in admin side have changed my website URL from `www.123.com/plans/1` to `www.123.com/plans/my-plan`.

After that my entire View (Page Browser) showing the articles (Associated with My-plans) with the heading and content with read more option.  But I need the customized Page layout, I am getting the correct layout for the  `www.123.com/plans/1/my-plan`

But it's not working for `www.123.com/plans/my-plan`.

Answer (score 1):

If I right understood your problem, you need to install [Pathauto module](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) and set up pattern for your taxonomy vocabulary (path to this settings admin/config/search/path/patterns).